# How to calculate a formula with undefined variable

Tags: ruby

I am trying to eval a string with undefined variable. For example: Formula = `2 * 3 + a` The result should return a string of `6 + a`. Can the eval method do something like that? Or, can you give me some ideas on how to do this?

Update: Thank you for all the inputs. I guess this is not as simple as i thought it would be. Let's say if I don't need to simplify the formula and all i need to do is to replace the variable with value in string?

Example:

```
a = { "Bob" => 82,
       "Jim" => 94,
       "Billy" => 58, ........ and more}
```

How do I convert this string

"2 * 3 + a["Bob"] * b"

to this:  "2 * 3 + 82 * b"

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There's nothing like this in programming languages, what you want is more likely mathematical function parsing.

Comment: What is your use-case? We might be able to give a better solution if you give some more context.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is complicated, and I don't think it is worth doing it.

You can use some gem to parse the string into a tree of tokens. Then, look for any node under which there is no undefined variable, and replace the node with the calculated value. After doing that, put the tree back to a string.

Answer (score 3):

What about using something like [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/) and making a parsing expression grammar to simplify your expressions? Look at the get started page where you are walked through a simple example in which Parslet reduces integer expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naïve solution:

```
str = "+ 1 * 2 - 3 / 2 + b - a"

terms = str.gsub(/^[^+-]+|[+-][^+-]+/).to_a
=> ["+ 1 * 2 ",
    "- 3 ",
    "+ b ",
    "- a"]

numbers, variables = terms.partition { |exp| eval(exp.to_s) rescue false }
=> [["+ 1 * 2 ", "- 3 "],
    ["+ b ", "- a"]]

numbers.map! { |exp| exp.gsub(/\d+/, &:to_f) }
=> ["+ 1.0 * 2.0 ",
    "- 3.0 / 2.0 "]

numbers.map! { |exp| eval(exp) }
=> [2.0, -1.5]

sum = numbers.reduce(:+)
=> "0.5"

result = "#{sum} #{variables.join}"
=> "0.5 + b - a"
```

Comment: You can remove white spaces from `str` in the first line (which leads to possibly less error prone code?)

Comment: Also `str = "124 + 3 * 2 + 20 + 100 / 2 - c"` doesn't work: returns `"150 +  100 / 2 - c"`.

Comment: That is why is a naïve solution. I think I got something, let me edit the answer.